# Altair : Make Interval Selection Line plot with dual axis and datetime x axis

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I am trying to make a dual y axis line plot with date time index as x axis, with interval selection, so far :

```
#base encoding the X-axis
brush = alt.selection(type='interval', encodings=['x'])
base = alt.Chart(yData.reset_index())
base = base.encode(alt.X('{0}:T'.format(yData.index.name), 
                         axis=alt.Axis(title=yData.index.name)))

py = base.mark_line()
py = py.encode(alt.X('date:T',scale = alt.Scale(domain = brush)),
               alt.Y('plotY', axis=alt.Axis(title='ylabel1')))
py = py.properties(width = 700, height = 230)


px = base.mark_line()
px = px.encode(alt.Y('plotX1', axis=alt.Axis(title='ylabel2')))
px = px.properties(width = 700, height = 230)

upper = (py + px).resolve_scale(y='independent')

lower = upper.copy()
lower = lower.properties(height=20).add_selection(brush)

p = alt.vconcat(upper, lower).configure_concat(spacing=0)
p
```

If I try to produce ***p*** I am getting the following error :

```
Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "selector045_x"
This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the JavaScript console for the full traceback
```

If I try to produce ***upper*** I get:

[image]

My dataframe :

[image]

Any idea how can I get interval selection here?

Also I keep getting this error while working with Altair, any idea how can I debug this?? I have no experience in java, and am using a Mac.

**EDIT**

After adding the selection to only one of the subplots,

```
brush = alt.selection(type='interval', encodings=['x'])
base = alt.Chart(yData.reset_index())
base = base.encode(alt.X('{0}:T'.format(yData.index.name), 
                         axis=alt.Axis(title=yData.index.name)))

py = base.mark_line()
py = py.encode(alt.X('date:T',scale = alt.Scale(domain = brush)),
               alt.Y('plotY', axis=alt.Axis(title='ylabel1')))
py = py.properties(width = 700, height = 230).add_selection(brush)


px = base.mark_line()
px = px.encode(alt.Y('plotX1', axis=alt.Axis(title='ylabel2')))
px = px.properties(width = 700, height = 230)

upper = (py + px).resolve_scale(y='independent')

lower = upper.copy()
lower = lower.properties(height=20)

p = alt.vconcat(upper, lower).configure_concat(spacing=0)
p
```

I am getting this :

[image]

(1) The selection isn't working

(2) And somehow i am getting an exact replica of `upper` for the lower plot

**EDIT -- This made it work **

```
brush = alt.selection(type='interval', encodings=['x'])
base = alt.Chart(yData.reset_index())
base = base.encode(alt.X('{0}:T'.format(yData.index.name), 
                         axis=alt.Axis(title=yData.index.name)))

py = base.mark_line(color='orange')
py = py.encode(alt.X('date:T',scale = alt.Scale(domain = brush)),
               alt.Y('plotY', axis=alt.Axis(title='ylabel1')),
              )
py = py.properties(width = 700, height = 230)


px = base.mark_line()
px = px.encode(alt.X('date:T',scale = alt.Scale(domain = brush)),
               alt.Y('plotX1', axis=alt.Axis(title='ylabel2')))
px = px.properties(width = 700, height = 230)

# upper = px
upper = (py + px).resolve_scale(y='independent')
lower = px.copy()
lower = lower.properties(height=20).add_selection(brush)

p = alt.vconcat(upper, lower).configure_concat(spacing=0)
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the selection to just `px` or `py` instead. If you add the same selection to both subcharts in a layer, it results in this error. This is a bug that should probably be fixed in Altair.

To be more concrete, your code should look like this:

```
# ...
px = px.properties(width = 700, height = 230).add_selection(brush)  # add selection here
# ...
lower = lower.properties(height=20)  # not here
# ...
```

Comment: Do you mean instead of `lower.properties(height=20).add_selection(brush)`?? I couldnt follow.., i have already used `scale` in only one of the subplots

Comment: Thanks jake for the response. But it still hasnt solved the issue. I have updated my question wrt the same

Comment: Hey, i was able to resolve the 'replica' part by changing `lower = upper.copy()` to `lower = px.copy()`. But the selection in `lower` is still not selecting in the `upper` plot

Comment: The issue is that you have set the domain in px, which is in both the lower and upper chart. You cannot set the scale of a subchart using a selection bound to that subchart (if the scale for the selection box is changing in response to changes to that selection box, things get a bit circular and ill-defined). What you need to do is restructure your chart such that ``add_selection`` is only called in the lower chart, and that ``alt.Scale(domain=...)`` is only added in the upper chart.